# Java Random: Seeding Problem

Tags: java, random

was wondering if you could help me out:

I have a method called `initializeAll`:

```
public final void initializeAll() {
//other stuff........
rand = new Random(353);
}
```

So I run the project and a GUI pops up, and some operations are carried out. When I press the "reset" button in my GUI, `intializeAll` is called again on the same class object. However, the operations that are carried out now are not the same as before, although they should be, since both times, a seed of 353 is being used on the newly created `Random` object. Why this difference? Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** sorry, its not "some operations are carried out". its that some initialization of agent population takes place. and each time, the initialization is different, although the same seed is used.

```
    private static int [][] initializePop(Random rand) {
        int[][] temp = new int[ROWS][COLS];
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                temp[row][col] = rand.nextInt(12) - 5;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

**SOLUTION:**

sorry for taking your time guys. i figured out the problem. right now, my application is a mess of various threads, swingworkers, etc i.e. very "thready".. apparently the random is actually working fine. the problem is with the GUI display, which does some funny things and displays some interesting value. so this is more of a threading problem. i'm redesigning the code now. so thanks again, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Are you quite sure the initializeAll() method is actually called when the reset button is pressed?

Comment: @Haakon - (+1) That was my first guess. Or, if initializeAll() is called, is the rand = new Random() statement getting hit?

Comment: @Haakon yes, it is called. physically stopping the run and doing a new run results in consistent results. its just that within one run, when "reset" is pressed, this happens.

Comment: And also, is the new Random object what is actually sent to initializePop? Could perhaps the "old" Random object have been retained somewhere?

Comment: thanks for your help jascav and haakon, im afraid its a slightly more complicated problem. random works just fine though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for taking your time guys. i figured out the problem. right now, my application is a mess of various threads, swingworkers, etc i.e. very "thready".. apparently the random is actually working fine. the problem is with the GUI display, which does some funny things and displays some interesting value. so this is more of a threading problem. so thanks again, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

> **Am I doing something wrong?**

Yes, it seems so. The `Random(long)` should reset the seed to the provided value. What ever the error is, it will be impossible for us to help you without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or at least more code.

```
Random rand = new Random(353);
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10));
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10));
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10));

rand = new Random(353);
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10));
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10));
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10));
```

Output:

```
7
5
5
7
5
5
```

Comment: thanks for your interest. this resetting does occur actually, but it occurs between runs and not within one run of this project.